# What does this complicated sentence mean?

Tags: ellipsis, comparative-constructions

What does this sentence mean?

> The houses for ordinary people aren't built of such material **as** is the King's house.

I don't understand this structure, especially ***as***.

Answer (score 2):

"As" is used when we compare two things, one of which is superior. In the sentence in question, the material that composes the houses of kings and ordinary people is compared. The statement simply tells us that the material used in the houses of kings is better than that used in the houses of ordinary people.

Comment: Greetings Divya, welcome to ELL. I've edited your answer a little to make it slightly easier to read. You may want to consider expanding on it and explaining why it is appropriate to use *as* here, and under what circumstances it would be wrong.